# Understanding JavaScript Code- passing a value to a object that is already defined by a function with a value

Tags: javascript, function

I am confused as to why this `console.log(twice(5))` prints 10. How is twice taking a value of 5 when it is already defined with a function which has its value?

```
function multipler(factor){
    return number => number * factor;
}
let twice = multipler(2);

console.log(twice(5));
```

but if i try to print `console.log(multipler(2))`, it just prints `[Function]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `multipler` (note that you probably meant `multiplier`) returns a function. So, calling `multipler(2)` gives you back this:

```
number => number * 2
```

which is a function equivalent to this:

```
function (number) {
    return number * 2;
}
```

That's what you stored in `twice`. So, `twice(5)` returns `10`.